# Is there a way to implement this as a responsive layout?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to implement this layout, so the `div_1` is always vertically centered relative to the parent's container and the `div_2` is always vertically centered relative to the right border of the `div_1` and the right border of the parent's container?
I've tried flexbox but could not make it
[image]